# Why are the Robospice response listener methods not being called?

Tags: android, robospice

I'm using Retrofit with RoboSpice. I'm making REST calls ok in places, but one call is a problem as the response listener is never called - neither onRequestFailure() nor onRequestSuccess()

## Activity

...after a user selects a UI option

```
CreateCustomerRequest createCustomerRequest = new CreateCustomerRequest("1001", "John", "Smith");
this.getSpiceManager().execute(createCustomerRequest, new CreateCustomerRequestListener());

private class CreateCustomerRequestListener implements com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener<ErrorResponse> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        // Never called
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
        // Never called
    }
}
```

## Request

```
public class CreateCustomerRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<ErrorResponse, EmbarApi> {

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public CreateCustomerRequest(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    super(ErrorResponse.class, EmbarApi.class);
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
}

@Override
public ErrorResponse loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getService().createCustomer(id, firstName, lastName);
}
```

I'm baffled as to why the listeners are not being called. I'm seeing very little logging from RS (just "main adding request to request queue")which seems strange, but as far as I can see RoboSpice is failing completely, but entirely silently. It's particularly confusing as I am making other REST calls within the app without issue.

Comment: I hope yout didn't forget to call spiceManager.start and apiceManager.shouldStop functions.

Comment: @jsidera you should add it as an answer, because that is EXACTLY what I had forgotten

Answer (score 7):

I hope yout didn't forget to call spiceManager.start and spiceManager.shouldStop functions.

They should be called at onStart and onStop functions at that context respectively.

Comment: Thought I was going nuts... it was working last night then not this morning.. forgot I'd commented out the start whilst debugging something else!